# It seems that I cannot get the socket factory from an RMI stub. Why is it so?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I am writing an application that uses RMI connection factories so that I can set a time-out on the client side before calling a remote method. I want to do this so the client can wait on a call to a remote method for a predetermined amount of time before giving up and abandoning the call.

I've created a socket factory that facilitates this mechanism. I create the remote stub with `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote, int, RMIServerSocketFactory, RMIClientSocetFactory)` so that the client can use the stub with the customised socket factory - the class definition of which is known to both devices.

The client's socket factory needs to set the time-out before it calls the server. The client decides the length of this time-out. I can craft a socket factory that works in this way. However, it seems that I cannot ensure on the client that the remote stub has this customised socket factory, and hence I cannot ensure that the client socket factory will create a client socket with a time-out.

I am wondering if there is a method which would work in a way like I would envisage `Remote.getClientFactory()` should work? This seems to me to be an obvious feature that isn't covered by the RMI spec. In the absence of this method, is there perhaps any well-used 'hack' to retrieve the client's socket factory on the client so a time-out can be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It wouldn't do you much good even if you could, as what you need is not the factory but the actual socket that is about to be used to make the call, and that's not predicable due to client-side connection pooling.
2. You could try adjusting [`sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html) prior to each call, but I have a nasty feeling it is only read once in the lifetime of the JVM.
3. Otherwise you could use a different socket factory per remote object, and a different remote object per remote interface, and a different remote interface per remote method, so that each socket factory is uniquely associated with a unique remote method ... and then assign a socket read timeout to each factory as required, but it is all still server-side; and it plays havoc with connection-pooling.
4. Or if you want the unofficial under-the-hood may-not-work-next-release non-compliant [don't use sun.* classes](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html) naughty version:

   ```
   RemoteRef   remoteRef;
   if (stub instanceof RemoteStub)
   {
       remoteRef = ((RemoteStub)stub).getRef();
   }
   else
   {
       // dynamic proxy
       RemoteObjectInvocationHandler   roih = (RemoteObjectInvocationHandler)java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(stub);
       remoteRef = roih.getRef();
   }
   if (remoteRef instanceof sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2)
   {
       // JRMP stub with client socket factory.
       // NB UnicastRef.getLiveRef() was added somewhere between 1.3 and 1.6.
       // Previously it was only obtainable via reflection.
       RMIClientSocketFactory csf = ((sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2)remoteRef).getLiveRef().getClientSocketFactory();
       // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
       // Note that 'csf' can still be null here, if you exported the remote object with an *explicitly null* client socket factory parameter.
   }
   ```

   However note the caveat I started with at (1). This may not do you much good at all.

Comment: Thanks again EJP. I have a penchant for option 4. It looks like I'll craft something that uses this option, and then wait for an updated RMI spec to tell me I'm naughty.

Comment: It's already naughty to use `sun.rmi.*` classes. I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for any changes whatsoever in RMI. Nothing has happened to it at all since 1.5 came out in 2004.

Comment: Hmmm... `RemoteStub` is deprecated... I'm supposing the stuff in the true case is for backwards compatibility... I haven't incorporated this logic into my solution. I just care that my thing works with the latest Java.

Comment: This `UnicastRef2` class is the only proprietary class. It appears that all that would be necessary for a revised API is to expose the client's socket factory in a `RemoteRef`. Hmmm... it would be nice...

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that you're right. It seems that the socket factory instance I get in my code is not the same instance that is used by the RMI runtime. I only call a single remote method, and this method accepts a single parameter. RMI was good for my development up to now in that I could abstract away the socket mechanics while I concentrated on other matters, but RMI is showing me its limits. Hence, I have resolved to ditch RMI and implement my message passing mechanism with sockets themselves.

Comment: It's the same instance but as it doesn't create the same socket it won't work.